# JavaScript - How to navigation one textbox to another textbox using arrow key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

JavaScript - How to navigation one textbox to another textbox using arrow key

I have many code test but not working please see below my html code and JavaScript Code

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 15px;">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date & Time</label>
            <input name="date_and_time" class="form-control"  readonly value="<?=date('Y-m-d H:i:s')?>" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Invoice Number</label>
            <input name="invoice_number" class="form-control"  readonly value="39" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Search Customer by Mobile / Name</label>
            <input name="customer_search_mobile_name" class="form-control"  value="" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript Code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).keydown(
    function(e)
    {    
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {  

            $(".form-control:focus").next().focus();

        }
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {      
            console.log('hi');
            $(".form-control:focus").prev().focus();

        }
    }
);
    </script>
```

Comment: Please supply your attempted JS code

Comment: Give tab-index bro

Comment: please check another time i have set js code

Comment: You have only one accessible input element. There is nothing else to go to

Comment: please write code below comment box

Answer (score 2):

Try this Code:

[Plunker Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Nofiden/foyfoe0q/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 15px;">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date & Time</label>
            <input name="date_and_time" class="form-control"   value="<?=date('Y-m-d H:i:s')?>" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Invoice Number</label>
            <input name="invoice_number" class="form-control"   value="39" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Search Customer by Mobile / Name</label>
            <input name="customer_search_mobile_name" class="form-control"  value="" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
var isShift = false;
$("input").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==16)
      isShift = true;
    if ((e.keyCode==40 || e.keyCode==39) && !isShift) {
      $(this).parent().parent().next().find('input').focus()
    }
      else  if ((e.keyCode==37 || e.keyCode==38) && !isShift) {
      $(this).parent().parent().prev().find('input').focus()
    }
});

$("input").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==16)
        isShift = false;
});
```

Comment: does not select value in textbox using shift key please ans me

Comment: Good catch HARDIK...Updated my answer and plunker link to handle text select using shift key

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="my_input">
<input class="my_input">
<input class="my_input">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.my_input').keyup(function(e) {    
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {  
      var inputs = $('.my_input');                // array of all inputs
      var index =  inputs.index(this);            // search which of the inputs is active
      var newIndex = (index+1) % inputs.length; // index + 1, but cycle back to 0
      $('.my_input').eq(newIndex).focus();
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
      var inputs = $('.my_input');                // array of all inputs
      var index =  inputs.index(this);            // search which of the inputs is active
      var newIndex = index - 1;               // index - 1
      if(newIndex<0) {
        newIndex = inputs.length - 1;             // cycle to last element
      }
      $('.my_input').eq(newIndex).focus();
    }
    return true;
  });
</script>
```